# Disable button depending on another node children amount in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, binding

I need to disable button depending on some element children amount.

I have tried something like this, which is not right:

```java
HBox userDataHBox = new HBox(new Label("1"), new Label("2"), new Label("3"));
Button btn = new Button();
btn.disableProperty().bind(
  Bindings.notEqual(userDataHBox.getChildren().size(), 3)
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
userDataHBox.getChildren().size()
```

just yields the current size of the list. Nothing to observe there. You could use [`Bindings.size`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#size(javafx.collections.ObservableList)) to get a `IntegerBinding` for the size that can be used:

```
btn.disableProperty().bind(
    Bindings.size(userDataHBox.getChildren()).isNotEqualTo(3));
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
btn.disableProperty().bind(
  Bindings.createBooleanBinding(()-> userDataHBox.getChildren().size() != 3, userDataHBox.getChildren())
);
```